# C++ Getting Location of std::out_of_range Exceptions

Tags: c++, debugging, exception

I'm working on a fairly lengthy program, and after running fine for awhile, suddenly I'm getting:

```
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::out_of_range'
 what(): basic_string::substr
```

Being new to exception handling, I did some research and found that I would likely get more information by adding the following to my main function:

```
int main(int argc, char **argv){
    try{
        //stuff
    }
    catch(exception const &exc){
        cerr << "Caught exception: " << exc.what() << endl;
    }
}
```

The result of this is the following output:

```
Caught exception: basic_string::substr
```

This isn't any more useful than the default output; it doesn't tell me anything about the line triggering the core dump (there are many substr calls in my program), the data the substr is attempting to process, etc. Is there a method for displaying information such as this in C++, or is my only option to use a debugger such as gdb?

Comment: What is wrong with using a debugger. Then it can tell you exactly what line throws the exception ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few ways.

1. As you said, a debugger - but that won't help you once the code is in production.
2. Nested exceptions and function try blocks. e.g.:

```
#include <exception>
#include <stdexcept>
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <iomanip>

void bar(std::string& s, int i)
try
{
    s.at(i) = 'A';
}
catch(...)
{
    std::ostringstream ss;
    ss << "error in bar(" << std::quoted(s) << ", " << i << ")";
    std::throw_with_nested(std::runtime_error(ss.str()));
}

void foo(std::string& s)
try
{
    bar(s, 6);
}
catch(...)
{
    std::ostringstream ss;
    ss << "error in foo(" << std::quoted(s) << ")";
    std::throw_with_nested(std::runtime_error(ss.str()));
}

void stuff()
try
{
    std::string s;
    foo(s);
}
catch(...)
{
    std::throw_with_nested(std::runtime_error("error in stuff()"));
}

void print_exception(std::ostream& os, const std::exception& e, int level =  0)
{
    os << std::string(level, ' ') << "exception: " << e.what() << '\n';
    try {
        std::rethrow_if_nested(e);
    } catch(const std::exception& e) {
        print_exception(os, e, level+1);
    } catch(...) {}
}

int main()
{
    try{
        stuff();
    }
    catch(std::exception& e)
    {
        print_exception(std::cerr, e);
        return 127;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

sample output:

```
exception: error in stuff()
 exception: error in foo("")
  exception: error in bar("", 6)
   exception: basic_string::at: __n (which is 6) >= this->size() (which is 0)
```

3. You could use `boost::stacktrace` in place of the above nested exception handling.

http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/f21bd35632a0a036